# Expose Web API hosted in AKS

Tags: azure-aks, webapi

I have an application deployed in Azure Kubernetes services which has a built in Web API service hosted on port 8080. I need to be able to expose this API to the outside of the K8 pod to the outside world.

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an Kubernetes Service and an Azure Load Balancer:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: public-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: public-app
```

The type LoadBalancer will create a Azure Load Balancer with a Public IP in the AKS management resource group.

Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard)

Comment: Do I have to set up an Ingress controller after creating a Loadbalancer so it will be able to reroute the traffic to my API? I noticed after setting up the Loadbalancer I was not exactly able to reach out to my APIs.

Comment: yes, to be able to use ingress you need an ingress controller. Your ingress-controller should have a service with the code example i send above.